# how to add a letter above a matrix in latex

Tags: latex

I am trying to write this in latex (using overleaf):
[image]

I wrote this code:

```
$\Theta = i\begin{bmatrix}
                 & \vdots & \\
                 \cdots &  \cdot &  \cdots\\
                 & \vdots & \\
                \end{bmatrix}$
```

[image]

I can't manage to write the j outside the matrix.
how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}


$\Theta = \begin{bNiceArray}[first-row,first-col]{ccc}
                 & & j & \\
                 & & \vdots & \\
                 i &\cdots &  \cdot &  \cdots\\
                 & & \vdots & \\
                \end{bNiceArray}$


\end{document}
```